# InfluxDB Show FieldKey for specific columns

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb, influxql

at the moment im using SHOW FIELD KEYS to get the data types all columns in influx, I am wondering how could I retrieve data types for specific columns only?

Current behavior:

```
SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM "database"."autogen"."measurement";

//Return all field keys and their types
```

i would like to achieve something like:

```
SHOW FIELD KEYS "columns1", "column2" FROM "database"."autogen"."measurement";
```